# Does setAutoCommit(true) commits past executions?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing, jdbc

```
public void batchUpdate() throws SQLException {

Statement stmt = null;
try {
    this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = this.connection.createStatement();


    stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO COFFEES VALUES('Amaretto_decaf', 49, 10.99, 0, 0)");

    stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO COFFEES " +"VALUES('Hazelnut_decaf', 49, 10.99, 0, 0)");

    int [] updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
    this.connection.commit();

} catch(BatchUpdateException b) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printBatchUpdateException(b);
} catch(SQLException ex) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(ex);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    this.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
}
}
```

**questions:**

1. Will calling connection.setAutoCommit(true) commit again already commited statements(through method `connection.commit()`) or will it just restore the  default state where you do not have to call the method commit yourself?
2. does closing the connection without calling `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` automatically calls the method or will it be still `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` next time it is opened?

Comment: What does 'commit again' mean? You can't commit the same change twice. Once it's committed it won't be in scope for any future commit statement?

Comment: @AlexPoole so calling `setAutoCommit(true)` after calling `connection.Commit()` will have no effect apart from restoring the connection default mode. isn't it?         what if i left the part `setAutoCommit(true)` after calling `connection.Commit()` and closed my connection, what will be the commit mode when i open the connection again? will it have been restored to it default mode which is `setAutoCommit(true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Statements already committed are not committed again.
2. It depends on your connection source: A connection pool may give you a connection with autoCommit=false when releasing it in that state, a new connection opens with the default value.

   > It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined. 
   >   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29

Comment: what is it meant by implementation-defined?

Comment: As Connection is an interface, it depends on the concrete class implementing that interface how a close() with an open transaction is handeld. It can result in commiting that transaction, rollbacking it or maybe an exception. For example (fictitious!) the jdbc driver for oracle databases may commit an open transaction while the implementation for mysql databases rolls back.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene - "implementation-defined" means that each class which implements the Connection interface is free to do whatever it likes. In this case it means that each class may decide to do something different if `close` is called when there is an active transaction. Some implementations may choose to commit the transaction; others may choose to roll it back; others may choose to raise an exception. Another way to look at it is that the phrase "implementation-defined" means "don't count on any consistent behavior". Best of luck.

Comment: @flo ok gotten that. am using mysql database and am calling `connection.commit()` before closing my connection. when i refresh my database, i can see the effects(transaction is committed).  now my question is do i have to call 'connection.setAutoCommit(true)` AFTER i have ALREADY called `connection.commit()` BEFORE closing my connection?  and (2)  IF there is no problem with that, WHAT will be the commit mode when i OPEN THE CONNECTION AGAIN? will it be have already been automatically restored to it default?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene It depends on your source. If you have a connection pool it doesn't close the real connection to the database but put it into the pool again you can end up with a "new" connection in autoCommit=false mode. Then your new queries on that connection are not commited automatically but reside in an implicit transaction which requires an explicit commit or reset of autoCommit to true to be persisted in the database. When you really open a new connection every time, there is no problem with autoCommit as a new Connection always starts with the default value (which usually is true)

Comment: @flo THAT'S THE POINT I WAS SEEKING!!.  you knocked it direct and made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

According to API

1) If setAutocommit is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, the transaction is committed.

2) If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

No other behaviour is defined

Comment: i did not understand your first point at all. how can one call setAutoCommit during a transaction? according to my way of knowing, it must be called before or after a transaction

Comment: @gikarasojokinene Transaction start in JDBC is implicit (as in the driver handles it), so when you are in a transaction (autoCommit = false, and you executed a statement), then calling `setAutoCommit(true)` will commit the active transaction as if you called `commit()` before calling `setAutoCommit(true)`

Comment: @gikarasojo kinene Why not? conn.setAutocommit(false); ..... stmt.executeUpdate(...); conn.setAutocommit(true)

Answer (score -2):

1. [click!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)
2. It is standardly true. When closing without committing it´s not committed.

Comment: i know When closing without committing it´s not committed. my question is does calling `setAutoCommit(true)` after calling `connection.Commit()` have any importance and what if i left `setAutoCommit(true)` after calling `connection.Commit()` and closed my connection, when i open it later, will AutoCommit mode be true or just the way i left it earier?

Comment: The result of closing with uncommited transactions can differ among differenet implementations of Connection.

Comment: @flo am closing after calling `connection.commit()` and leaving `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` and when i refresh my database, i can see that results have already been committed whether i type or ignore `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` as long as i have called the method `connection.commit()`.  my question is, because i don't see  the importance of calling `connection.setAutoCommit(true)`  after i have already called `connection.commit()` is there any problem with that?

Comment: If your transactions are once committed you cannot commit them again?! If you set autocommit true after committing your connection it only have an effect on following transactions. In your case you don´t have following, so it doesn´t make a difference. If you close your Connection with con.close() and open it later, your autocommit is always true by default.

Comment: @gikarasojokinene It depends on your source. If you have connections pools which don't close the connection to the database but put them into the pool again you can end up with a "new" connection in autoCommit=false mode. Then your new queries on that connection are not commited automatically but reside in an implicit transaction which requires an explicit commit or reset of autoCommit to true to be persisted in the database. When you really open a new connection every time, there is no problem with autoCommit as a new Connection always starts with the default value (which usually is true).